# How can I make a Lifesteal system inside unity using C#?

Tags: c#

I want to make a lifesteal system in my game,I dont know how to do it. After a lot of reasearch on google, I found nothing.Can anyone help on how to do it?
I don't mean to give me the code ofcurse but to help me just think about how it will work. I work on C#

The game is like this:

My player have some stats like health, damage, etc. The player attacks the enemy with a sword. Enemy has his own health and when it dies it gives xp to the player. I have a heal function in my player so heal can be added via Health potions. And the question is how is it supposed to heal the player based on his hits? I mean you land a hit = 20 damage you get back 2hp(e.g 10% lifesteal).

Comment: What is a lifesteal system?

Comment: Lifesteal is when you atack the enemy you gain back some health(You steal some of his life and add it to yours.Moba games have this system and many other games)

Comment: What is the difficulty you're having with that? Keep in mind that nobody but you knows anything about your game at this point. You haven't described anything about it or the problem.

Comment: I edited the question so is more clear to the reader to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to execute the health function everytime that the player attacks the enemy, you can do it like this:

```
public float playerHealth = 100;
int percentage = 20;

public void healPlayer()
{
   playerHealth += (attackDamage * (percentage / 10)); 
}
```

This code is adding the 20% of the amount of damage that the player has done to the enemy, dividing the percentage between 10 and multiplying it by the amount of the damage.

You can add experience to the player when the enemy dies, executing a function like this:

```
public float playerExperience = 10;

public void addExperience()
{
  playerExperience += 2;
}
```

Comment: But then will the player heal even if he didnt hit the enemy?I mean can attack the air and get health like that?

Comment: The heal player function must be executed only when the player hits the enemy

Comment: Ok i get it.Thank you so much for your help.I have already managed to make an XP system but thank you anyways.

Comment: I hope it helps you aswell